# Easiest way to connect both of my monitors?

Tags: display, gpu, dual-gpu

I have two outdated but perfectly working monitors that both have DVI-D and VGA. My PC has a Ryzen 1700X CPU with 24 GB of RAM and an SSD. This is relevant because my current GPU is a GT 610 (with a VGA, DVI-D, and one HDMI port), which obviously is my current bottleneck. Therefore, I decided to get an RX 580. Unfortunately, the one I picked (‘twas cheapest, what can I say?) has only one DVI-D port, and I can’t fit both of my current monitors on to the one graphics card. The easiest solution would be to get an adapter or a new display, but I would like to how I could use the VGA port from the old GPU in conjunction with the DVI-D port on the new GPU without any substantial performance losses.?

Comment: Single-link DVI-D is electrically compatible with HDMI... what's wrong with an adapter / cable and only one graphics card?

Comment: @Attie I could totally do that, and will probably do that in the near future. I just don’t have it on me right now, and was curious to see if there was a better/weirder/more interesting solution to the problem